# Bootstrap Input Group not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align multiple form components in a row, however I got some wired behaviors. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

As you could see, I would like to have the set mark up checkbox, label, amount markup input (number) and markup type (select) in the same line, and here is what I have tried:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="price_selection_page" class="border">
   <form class="mt-3 p-2 d-flex">
      <div class="input-group d-flex w-25">
         <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox" value="" id="set-mark-up-check">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="set-mark-up-check">Set Markup</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group d-flex">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input class="form-input" type="number" value="" id="mark-up-amount-input">
         </div>
         <select id="mark-up-select" class="custom-select">
            <option value="percentage">% By Percentage</option>
            <option value="amount">% By Amount</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But this is what I got when I tried to render it in the browser:
[image]
As you could see, the checkbox and the label are in the same line, but the number input is on a new line, and the select box is also on a new line instead of showing up in the same line as with the number input field.

I am using bootstrap 5 and I would really appreciate some help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `"d-flex"` to flex out the content into one row and remove some of your unnecessary  tags.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="mt-3 p-2 d-flex">
  <div class="input-group d-flex w-25">
    <input class="form-check-input me-3" type="checkbox" value="" id="set-mark-up-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="set-mark-up-check">Set Markup</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group d-flex">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="form-input" type="number" value="" id="mark-up-amount-input">
    </div>
    <select id="mark-up-select" class="custom-select">
      <option value="percentage">% By Percentage</option>
      <option value="amount">% By Amount</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not working, I am sorry, would you mind run the code snippet button under your own answer? you would see now the select box is directly under the number input field

Comment: I just modified the answer, the previous answer works, but it just the snippet console window too small to fit all contents. Please refresh the page and re-run the snippet. thanks

Comment: it works in the code snippet, and I copied and pasted the exact same code, but it is not working on my side though...

Comment: Could you confirm the correct Bootstrap version you have included in your page? Or update the question with you entire page, so we can debug more.

Comment: just edited it, and I also updated what it looks like now

Comment: Seems like your have a CSS styles override the "select" box, check your CSS stylesheet or right click on "Select" box to inspect the css style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232612/discussion-between-stevenxxccc-and-jacky-s).

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```html
<form class="mt-3 p-2">
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="set-mark-up-check">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="set-mark-up-check">Set Markup</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col input-group">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input class="form-input" type="number" value="" id="mark-up-amount-input">
         </div>
         <select id="mark-up-select" class="custom-select">
            <option value="percentage">% By Percentage</option>
            <option value="amount">% By Amount</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ for further information.

---

### **Edit**

<!doctype html>

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <form class="mt-3 p-2">
            <div class="form-row row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="set-mark-up-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="set-mark-up-check">Set Markup</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <input class="form-input" type="number" value="" id="mark-up-amount-input">
                        </div>
                        <select id="mark-up-select" class="custom-select">
                            <option value="percentage">% By Percentage</option>
                            <option value="amount">% By Amount</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```